# JsonParseException in json parsing by gson

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I have issue in json parsing using gson

my json text is

```
{
    **"message": [**
        {
            "id": "123",
            "trackid": "GPN-GET-HYGH",
            "category": "0",
            "subject": "new message",
            "dt": "2013-04-02 14:52:48",
            **"message": "Hewlrj",**
            "repliername": null,
            "attachment_name": "image.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "replies": [
        {
            "id": "165",
            "replyto": "123",
            "name": "962788161885",
            "message": "Hellooo\nHjkhjkhjkhkjh\nHjkhkjhjkhkh",
            "dt": "2013-04-02 15:53:11",
            "attachments": "",
            "staffid": "0",
            "rating": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created two class one for message and second for replies with above fields

but getting exception

```
com.google.myjson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "Hewlrj"
```

please help me

**EDITED**

my message class structure is look like(without getter setter..i have removed it)

```
public class message {
    int id;
    String trackid;
    String category;
    String subject;
    String dt;
    String message;
    String repliername;
    String attachment_name;
}

public class TicketList {

    ArrayList<message> message;
}


try{
       Gson json=new Gson();
       object=json.fromJson(mJSONString,TicketLis.class);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("error in gson parsing");
      ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: Message and Replies shouldn't be classes. They should be a arraylist<Message> and ArrayList<Reply>

Comment: @rgksugan you are right, Its my fault to write question, i have created list of message and reply in third class

Comment: @rgksugan If those are not classes then how can generate ArrayList with Message and Reply objects?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am getting exception in parsing  Gson json=new Gson();
     object=json.fromJson(mJSONString,clazz);

Comment: @PareshMayani I meant they should not be classes in the response. I mean they should be a list of classes.

Comment: @rgksugan Make sure what are you saying :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have "message": "Hewlrj" in the json and probably you defined a class looking like :

```
class Message {
  private Message message;
}
```

Thus Gson is expecting to find a json object for message but not a string. The solution would be to replace private Message message with private String message;